# ios:Spinner in custom cell disappears after scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I created a custom cell with a hidden spinner and hidden text "Load More". These fields are unhidden for the last cell so that the user can click it to request more data. I have it woking so that when the user clicks the last cell the spinner starts, but when the user scrolls the cell out of view and back again the spinner is not shown. Any help will be appreciated.:)

I have a custom cell that is a subclass of UITableViewCell:

```
@interface BrowseListCell : UITableViewCell{
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
IBOutlet UILabel *name;
IBOutlet UILabel *loadMore;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *image;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *loadMore;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@end
```

Inside the tableViewController I have:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [_dataController countOfList]+1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

// Configure the cell...
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BrowseListCell";

BrowseListCell *cell = (BrowseListCell *)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [_cell autorelease];
    _cell = nil;
}
if(indexPath.row==[_dataController countOfList]){
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        cell.name.text=nil;
        cell.image.image = nil;
        cell.loadMore.hidden = YES;
        return cell;
    }else{
        cell.name.text=nil;
        cell.image.image = nil;
        cell.loadMore.hidden = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        _spinner = [cell.spinner retain];
        _loadCell = [cell retain];
        return cell;
    }
}
if(_dataController!=nil){
    BrowseProduct *productAtIndex = [_dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    if(productAtIndex!=nil){
        cell.name.text = productAtIndex.name;
        cell.image.image = productAtIndex.image;
        cell.loadMore.hidden=YES;
    }

}

return cell;
```

}

Inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row==[_dataController countOfList]){
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        //do nothing
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Loading");
        [_spinner startAnimating];
        _loadCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        NSString *startFromId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_dataController countOfList]];
        NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"loadMore" object:startFromId];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotification:notification];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add the spinner in the if(cell == nil) condition

Comment: I have the spinner in a custom cell that is a subclass of UITableViewCell. I just start and stop. Do you mean start it in if(cell==nil) condition; I dont know what add means.

Comment: You can take one boolean variable .. In did select set boolean variable value is YES.. and in cell for row at index You can check if boolean variable value is yes then set property of spinner i.e   [_spinner startAnimating]; otherwise stop.... make sure that after loading succesfully you have to set boolean variable value is NO

Comment: @EliMiller did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Tendulkar I havent tried what you mentioned above. I will get back to you today.

Comment: welcome dude Eli Miller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(spinnerIsOn){
            [_spinner startAnimating];
        }else{
            [_spinner stopAnimating];
        }
```

Added following to reloadTableViewData:

```
spinnerIsOn=NO;
```

Added the following to didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
spinnerIsOn = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code , to show spinner even after stop animating

```
 spinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
```

Please refer the apple  link for [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)

Comment: yes this will leave the spinner but the _loadCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; becomes YES again. It seems as when I scroll the loadMore cell out of view everything gets reset.

Comment: This doesn't work.When I scroll the last cell off the screen the spinner stops. 1st when I load the tableview it is stopped. 2nd I click the cell the spinner starts. 3rd scroll the cell out of view and back again it stops (even if hide when stopped is not set).

Answer (score 0):

You can also subclass layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.spinner.startAnimating()

    // populate data, for instance: download an image from the net

    cell.spinner.stopAnimating()

    return cell
}
```

And of course, `spinner.hidesWhenStopped` must be `true`, which is by default.