# How to load spinner-list on particular cell item when we tapped on item button

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I have created one tableList and I have added one button on tableList cell.

When I tap on a particular cell item button it should load a spinner list.

The problem is when I scroll through tableList and tap on a "2" cell item button. The spinner list is loading on first cell and when I click "1" cell item button the spinner list is loading on fourth cell.

How can I resolve this problem?

### code:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
{
    UITableView * MaintableView;
    NSMutableArray * Mainarray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    MaintableView.delegate = self;
    MaintableView.dataSource = self;
    MaintableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [MaintableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [MaintableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [Mainarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(ButtonACtion:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 300.0, 20.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}

-(void)ButtonACtion :(id)sender{

    //Here i am loading spinner list when tapped on button
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of cell reuse.

You may want to have a model which your cell is binded to and a custom cell with a spinner into.

Then on cellForRow you get right model for your array and set cell.spinnerIsVisible to true or something like that.

Take a look at this SO questions:

[ios:Spinner in custom cell disappears after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871070/iosspinner-in-custom-cell-disappears-after-scrolling)